# Azure contributor access from Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, azure, rbac

As security best practice our Client has restricted developer roles to Contributor on their Azure Portal resource group. All is fine but this seriously restricts using any kind of azure integration (deployments, server explorer, cloud explorer etc) from Visual Studio if we use the Contributor role to sign in to azure from Visual Studio. We are working on typical MSBI services like data lake analytics (usql), azure Analysis services, dw. And we cannot use any of the visual studio azure connectivity features.

I found a solution, to use a management cert. But MS site warns against using this as it will allow access to all azure resources defeating the purpose of contributor restrictions.

Could I please request for any guidance?

Comment: Why not just have the client create a Resource Group configured for you, for dev/test purposes, with appropriate access privileges? Not sure what else you can do, if the client locked you out, aside from running your own Azure subscription for dev/test.

Comment: Client created a resource group and provided access with RBAC. However to work with Visual Studio we need to have a subscription which you do not get unless you are associated as a subscription admin/co-admin. I stand corrected if I am wrong on this. I believe MS had created the RBAC concept to fine tune access management - so you could give ownership to subsections where users could have complete ownership. However if this prevents using visual studio on that area then I am mistaken about the model. Perhaps use VSTS that gets code from VControl and then uses higher role to deploy to azure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use RBAC'd accounts with VS, only the "legacy" features will not recognize them - e.g. Cloud Service Publish, Server Explorer (for this use Cloud Explorer instead).

Anything recent (AzureRM Tools, Cloud Explorer, Web Tools, Connected Svcs, Team Explorer) will work with RBAC

What features are you having trouble with?

Comment: Thanks for your post. We are using Azure Data Lake Store, Data Lake Analytics, Azure Analysis server, ADF and a few more things. The challenges we are facing are - a) Cannot view any of the above resources in server explorer/cloud explorer of VS when we create an azure connection using contributor user access. VS complains there are not subscriptions for the user. We cannot publish using ADF. We cannot run USQL scripts not register USQL assemblies on Azure because we donot see the analytics server to start with on the server explorer. These are some of the problems.

Comment: I retried using the contributor role access in Cloud Explorer -> Azure account setting. It gives the error "We didn't find any Microsoft Azure subscriptions associated with your account.

Sign up for a subscription
"

Comment: Hmm... if you're still having issues and want to email me (bmoore at microsoft) and we can try to debug.

Comment: Sorry @bmoore-msft couldn't connect with you over email - perhaps my emails are not reaching you :(

Comment: Upon further investigation I seem to have succeeded in adding a contributor to the Cloud explorer from my faulty subscription. Looking into Fiddler output I realized that VS is using VSTS apis for authentication. So I decided to setup a VSTS account and linked it to my Azure AD directory for the subscription. I then added the user as a member in the VSTS project. I checked that I could log on with the user's azure credentials. Now when I tried to connect via VS Cloud explorer I was able to log on - it shows the subscription in the explorer. Would anyone have any idea if this was the problem?

Comment: Sorry Shaswata - I was at a conference last week...  re: the problem, there are cases where, when working with a new account, you need to use that account to login to VSTS before VS will find subscriptions for it... I don't quite know all the nuances of when that's required, but it sounds like that's your situation.  Another test you could do is with a new account - if you see the same behavior, just log into VSTS (you shouldn't need to assign it to a project) and then remove/add the account in VS again.

Comment: Thanks a lot bmoore-msft for letting me know the situation where this can occur.  I suspect you are right. I will try with another account using the steps you mentioned and keep you posted. And no worries about the delay.

Comment: One clarification- should I use the following steps? a. Create a VSTS account for the user's AAD organization email (is that allowed or is a microsoft id required for VSTS account creation) b. Login to VSTS with AAD org account  Can you please validate? Does the VSTS account need to be linked to Azure subscription? Thanks again for your guidance... Shaswata

Comment: you can use either orgId or MSA for the login - and yes you will have to give it access to the Azure subscription via the Azure portal.

Comment: Though I have not been able to try the final test mentioned above as of yet for lack of time (since things are working fine now and been busy with project delivery), to acknowledge the guidance received from bmoor-msft I would mark the above set of conversation as a valid answer that guided me quite a lot in the trouble shooting.